# Why am I getting a slight error when trying to implement current time in C++

Tags: c++

when I enter this code

```
unsigned seed = time(0);
    
srand(seed);
```

I keep getting this error and I dont understand why?

Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int'
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int'

am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Simple google search gives you a working example: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

Comment: What do you not understand? 'time_t' (aka 'long') has more bits than 'unsigned int' has, and loses precision.

Comment: To be more specific, unsigned means unsigned int, which normally takes 32 bits in modern machine, long or time_t takes 64 bits. Strong typed languages needs you to explicitly do conversion of the types. Or just define it as `time_t`

Comment: Semi-related: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) An excellent presentation on why you shouldn't use `rand` anymore and what you should use instead.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that `sizeof(time_t) > sizeof(unsigned int)` on your computer, and a sufficiently large `time_t` value would be truncated when it's converted to an `unsigned int`.  If you are ok with that just use an explicit cast:

```
srand((unsigned int) time(0));
```

As an aside, even if they were the same size, a cast from a signed value to an unsigned one might also be unexpected, i.e. on my computer `(unsigned) -1 == 4294967295`.